# mounting a linux directory on a VMS machine

Tags: mount, nfs, vms

We have a VMS machine which must mount a directory residing on a linux server.
I am responsible for the linux side, another guy is reponsible for the VMS side.

So far his attempts to mount the directory failed

```
insufficient privilege or object protection violation
```

In order to find out on which side the problem lies, i want to make sure i haven't forgotten anything. This is what i did:

- created a user 'microct'
- created a directory '/raid1/microct' owned by user 'microct'
- added the vms machine to /etc/exports

  /raid1/microct   130.60.xxx.yyy(rw,async,subtree_check,no_root_squash)
- added the VMS machine in /etc/hosts.allow (even though i don't know if all of these are necessary)

  lockd:   localhost, 130.60.xxx.yyy

  rquotad: localhost, 130.60.xxx.yyy

  portmap: localhost, 130.60.xxx.yyy

  mountd:  localhost, 130.60.xxx.yyy

  statd:   localhost, 130.60.xxx.yyy
- restarted NFS

  /etc/init.d/nfsd restart

Is there anything i overlooked?

The VMS Guy said he needs UID and GID of the "NFS user", but i have no idea what that might be...

Thank You

Comment: While I won't be able to answer, it's likely that anyone who could answer will want to know which TCP/IP stack is in use on the VMS side. Likely answers would include Multinet (from Process) or "TCP/IP Services" (from HP). Your VMS Guy should know.

Comment: From what little I recall of *nix, when you created the `microct` account you (implicitly or explicitly) would have assigned a group identification (GID) and user identification (UID) to the account. (Possibly in octal or some other popular radix.) Those would be the magic numbers needed on the VMS side to request a suitable NFS connection.

Comment: @HABO Yes i gave these number to the VMS guy and he created a "proxy" with them. Looking at the logfile" /var/log/messages" i saw that whenever the VMS mount was performed, an "authenticated mount request" appeared, immediately followed by an "authenticated unmount request". We have no idea who sends this unmount request and why...

Answer (score -1):

After experimenting with mounting the directory from Windows i noticed that mountd wrote a "illegal port" message:

> Dec  8 12:14:28 aim-yeti mountd[4705]: refused mount request from 130.60.126.112 for /raid1/microct (/raid1/microct): illegal port 58152

In the man page for export around i found that in /etc/exports i could add an option "insecure" to an export, which allows connections through ports higher than 1024.

Adding this option to the export, i was able to mount the directory from Windows.
Surprisingly, this also helped in the case of VMS, even though there was never any "illegal port" message when we tried to mount from the VMS machine...

So - i have no explanation why this works, but i am happy it does work now.

Comment: Now you need to "accept" your own answer, so that this question doesn't come up as unanswered.